# What would be the best term to describe laboratory equipment?

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology, terminology, scientific-language

How can I say "lab equipment" in German? By that I mean items like centrifuges, blotting and chromatography devices, autoclaves. Not furniture and not clothes. I am picking between **Laborausrüstung** and **Laborausstattung**. But I found other words: **Laborbedarf** and **Laboreinrichtung**. What is the difference between all of these terms? Which one should I pick?

Should I just write **Laborgeräte**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your suggested terms work - more or less. They should be understood. German composites can take a variety of meanings and it is often possible to establish the same meaning via different words.

**Laborausrüstung**
This is probably not fitting very well. "Ausrüstung" indeed means "equipment" but in this context it is not idiomatic. "Ausrüstung" is usually used to describe equipment one wears for a certain task, i.e. "Bergsteigerausrüstung" for the equipment someone uses to climb mountains.

**Laborausstattung**
This is a good word to describe major devices one lab might have that another doesn't. For instance:

> Dieses *Labor* ist mit einem FACS-Gerät *ausgestattet*.
> Die *Laboraustattung* umfaßt ein FACS-Gerät.

**Laborbedarf**
This is mostly used for expendable goods: distilled water, medicinic gloves, beakers, filter paper, spatulas and the like. It is not commonly used for permanently installed devices.

**Laboreinrichtung**
This is also a good word for your purpose and similar to "Laborausstattung". The main meaning of "Einrichtung" without any context is "furniture", but in this context could be translated by "feature" or "facility", which fits.

**Laborgerät**
Is also a good word you can use, but it is unspecific. It can, depending on context, mean "Laborbedarf" (like beakers) as well as bigger and permanent devices.

My suggestion for you is "Laborausstattung", closely followed by "Laboreinrichtung" and "Laborgerät". "Laboreinrichtung" would be a good fit but (to my knowledge) isn't used in this way and "Laborbedarf" describes mostly expendable goods, not facilities.

Comment: Im Wesentlichen stimme ich zu. Aber zur Laborausstattung zählt m.E. nicht nur (Groß)gerät, sondern durchaus alles, was kein Verbrauchsmaterial ist, d.h. auch Kleingeräte und Werkzeug wie Netzgeräte, Schraubenzieher, Messschieber, vorkonfektionierte Kabel, Lötkolben, Bunsenbrenner, Messgefäße etc als auch nötige Möbel (also Einrichtung im engeren Sinne), Abzüge und ggf. kann man sogar weitergehen und fest installierte Anschlüsse wie Gase oder Strom und Netzwerk(e) dazuzählen.

Comment: In Summe würde ich deshalb "Laborausstattung" als das  vermutlich best passende, weil breitest angelegte Wort empfehlen

Comment: @planetmaker: This is actually why I suggested "Laborausstattung", as you can see in my last sentence.

Comment: Von '-bedarf' spricht man oft im kaufmännischen Sinn, hier z.B. von Handelsunternehmen, bei denen man Laborgerätschaften und, wie in der ersten Antwort dargestellt, vor allem Verbrauchsmaterialien fürs Labor erwerben kann.

Answer (score 0):

**Laborgeräte** ist in der Tat der beste Begriff, wenn Du Verbrauchsmaterialien und Mobiliar ausschließen willst.

Mein englisches Sprachverständnis würde aber vermuten, dass diese bei "lab equipment" nicht ausgeschlossen sind - ich bin jedoch kein Muttersprachler/Englisch. Zählen Schallschutzelemente zum Audioequipment? Sind es Geräte?

RHas Hinweis auf die Bergsteigerausrüstung finde ich unpassend, da Bergsteiger keine Möbel ins Gebirge bringen. Die Ausrüstung eines Labors kann aber eine Absaugvorrichtung beinhalten, die in die Möbel (Arbeitstische) oder gar die Architektur integriert ist. Gummihandschuhe würde ich sowohl unter Ausrüstung als auch unter Ausstattung subsumieren.

Equipment ist auch im Deutschen weit verbreitet, je nach Sparte - bei einem Kindergarten wohl seltener, als beispielsweise bei Computer- oder Audioequipment.

Aber auch hier zählen Verbrauchsmaterialien und Kleinteile wie Kabelbinder dazu, wobei es schwer zu argumentieren sein wird, wieso ein Kabelbinder kein Gerät sein soll.

**Laborinstrument** ist auch eine gute Alternative zu Laborgerät.